# How to hide name and age in data People a = Person { name::a , age::Int} deriving Show in haskell

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have

```
data People a = Person { name::a , age::Int} deriving Show
```

in Hugs when I type

```
> Person "Alihuseyn" 20
```

I get `Person {name = "Alihuseyn", age = 20}`
but I want to get `Person  Person "Alihuseyn" 20`.

I mean how can I hide the mention of name and age without changing data?

Comment: Then don't derive the `Show` instance, but write your own. If you define a type with labelled fields, the derived `Show` instance includes the braces and field names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can always provide a custom `Show` instance for all your types if you want:

```
data People a = Person { name::a , age::Int} 

instance (Show a) => Show (People a) where
    show (Person name age) == "Person " ++ show name ++ " " ++ show age
```

Or alternatively and less elegantly, write custom accessors:

```
data People a = Person a Int deriving Show
name (Person n _) = n
age (Person _ a) = a
```

Either way, you have to change the declaration of `People`, otherwise you are stuck with the derived `Show` instance.

As a side note, if you have a data type with only a single constructor, you typically name the constructor after the type, so it would be `data Person a = Person { name :: a, age :: Int }`

Answer (score 7):

This uses `GHC.Generics` to provide a `showsPrecDefault`, which can be easily used to define a `Show` instance.

```
data Person a = Person { name :: a, age :: Int } deriving Generic

instance Show a => Show (Person a) where showsPrec = showsPrecDefault

>>> Person "Alihuseyn" 20
Person "Alihuseyn" 20
```

The definition of `showsPrecDefault` is below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    DeriveGeneric
  , FlexibleContexts
  , FlexibleInstances
  , KindSignatures
  , TypeOperators
  , TypeSynonymInstances #-}
import GHC.Generics

class GShow f where
  gshowsPrec :: Int -> f a -> ShowS

instance GShow U1 where
  gshowsPrec _ U1 = id

instance Show c => GShow (Rec0 c) where
  gshowsPrec p = showsPrec p . unK1

instance GShow f => GShow (D1 d f) where
  gshowsPrec p = gshowsPrec p . unM1

instance Constructor c => GShow (C1 c U1) where
  gshowsPrec _ c@(M1 U1) = showParen (isInfix c) (showString (conName c))

instance (Constructor c, GShow (M1 i c f)) => GShow (C1 c (M1 i c f)) where
  gshowsPrec = gshowsPrec'

instance (Constructor c, GShow (f :+: g)) => GShow (C1 c (f :+: g)) where
  gshowsPrec = gshowsPrec'

instance (Constructor c, GShow (f :*: g)) => GShow (C1 c (f :*: g)) where
  gshowsPrec = gshowsPrec'

gshowsPrec' :: (Constructor c, GShow f) => Int -> C1 c f p -> ShowS
gshowsPrec' p c@(M1 f) =
  showParen (p > 10) $
  showParen (isInfix c) (showString (conName c)) .
  showChar ' ' .
  gshowsPrec 11 f

isInfix :: Constructor c => t c (f :: * -> *) a -> Bool
isInfix c = case conFixity c of
  Infix _ _ -> True
  _ -> False

instance GShow f => GShow (S1 s f) where
  gshowsPrec p = gshowsPrec p . unM1

instance (GShow a, GShow b) => GShow (a :+: b) where
  gshowsPrec p (L1 a) = gshowsPrec p a
  gshowsPrec p (R1 b) = gshowsPrec p b

instance (GShow a, GShow b) => GShow (a :*: b) where
  gshowsPrec p (a :*: b) =
    gshowsPrec (p + 1) a .
    showChar ' ' .
    gshowsPrec (p + 1) b

showsPrecDefault :: (Generic a, GShow (Rep a)) => Int -> a -> ShowS
showsPrecDefault p = gshowsPrec p . from
```